# Отступ первого и последнего tab-а в TabLayout в развёрнутом CollapsingToolbarLayout программно как в приложении Google Play Пресса

Tags: java, android, android-tabs, collapsing-toolbar-layout, android-tablayout

**Дано:**

В гугловом новостном приложении при разворачивании `CollapsingToolbarLayout` `tab`-ы (первый и последний; слева и справа соответственно) анимированно сдвигаются в сторону (см gif).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что пробовал:**

1. В ресурсах библиотеки поддержки я нашёл только один `xml` аттрибут `tabContentStart`, отвечающий за отступ первого `tab`-а слева. При этом сеттера для этого атрибута я в доках не нашёл. Как и его аналога для последнего `tab`-а.
2. Пробовал получать View tab-а и проставлять ему margin/padding, но при этом, хоть tab и отображается как надо, индикатор (полоса-выделение под табом) занимает всё пространство до края экрана.

Засим

**Вопрос:**

Каким образом программно можно задать отступ первого и последнего табов как на гифке выше? (отловить события разворачивания тулбара я могу, а вот к табам мне не подступиться никак).

**P.S.** Ответ - надо проставить `padding` первому ребёнку `TabLayout`, подробнее ниже.

Comment: мне почему от думается, что там в разметку слева, а затем справа от `TabLayout`  просто добавляется пустое пространство (например [`Space`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Space.html) ). Ну и анимируется все это. Это лишь предположение.

Comment: ну так можно в `Опциях разработчика` включить `Показать границы макета`, иногда очень помогает понять как организована разметка у приложения.

Comment: @pavlofff, вы не угадали) Сам так поначалу думал, но оказалось всё гораздо проще - см. мой ответ, если интересно.

Comment: @ermak0ff, да, что-то я про это забыл совсем) Правда, в данном случае пользование сего инструмента не помогло, пришлось сорцы читать(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Кратко:**

Решается задача проставлением левого и правого `padding` первому ребёнку `TabLayout`:

```
TabLayout tab = ...;
View firstChildOfTabLayout = tab.getChildAt(0);
firstChildOfTabLayout.setPadding(100, 0, 100, 0);
```

**Подробно:**

С *пятого* раза разглядел таки в [сорцах](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java) `TabLayout`, что атрибут `tabContentStart` просто устанавливается как левый `padding` первому и единственному ребёнку `TabLayout`-а. Первый он и единственный - т.к. `TabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView` и является при этом `SlidingTabStrip` (что нам, правда, и не важно в данной ситуации).

Таким образом, отловив в `onOffsetChanged` нужные моменты надо просто проставить паддинги скролящемуся элементу `HorizontalScrollView`. Подобный подход полностью реализует требуемое поведение.

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset)
    {
        if (collapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight() + verticalOffset < 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbarLayout))
        {
            View viewInTabsScrollView = tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
            viewInTabsScrollView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            View viewInTabsScrollView = tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
            viewInTabsScrollView.setPadding(100, 0, 100, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

**Результат:**

[image: тест]